# How to load multiple number of pages dynamically in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have this table `instruction_title` and this table `instruction_body`. One instruction title can have one or many instruction body. In my resource controller `instController` the index funtion is showing the list of instruction title, onclick it is going to the show function and showing which bodies it has.

If the instruction id is 25, it is going to `/instructions/25`. 
But I need something like `/instructions/25/Body1` with a next button if it has body2 and on next it will go to `/instructions/25/Body2` and go on.

Comment: can you provide view you get at /instruction/25 then i can help and provide database table for it

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

---

in your routes :

```
Route::get('/instructions/{titleId}/{bodyName}', 'instController@index')->name('titleIndex');
```

---

And in your blade :

```
@php 

$currentBodyId = $next = \DB::table('instruction_body')
->orderBy('id', 'asc')->select('id')
->first();

$next = \DB::table('instruction_body')
->where('titleId', $YOUR_TITLE_ID)
->where('id', '>', $currentBodyId)
->sortBy('id')
->first();

$nextUrl = ($next !== null) ? $next->YOUR_BODY_NAME : '#' ;

@endphp
```

And in your next button in blade:

```
@if ($nextUrl != '#')

<a href="{{ route('titleIndex', ['bodyName' => $nextUrl]) }}">
    Next
</a>

@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

@behnam's has some bad practice. Never have logic to query data in the presentation layer! That was the reason why MVC architecture was built.

But what you could do is attach a relationship `one-to-many` for both Models: 
[Read here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Then you can fetch bodies that belongs to a specific title like:

```
//in your controller
    $datas = Title::find(25)->with('bodies');
```

Then you can loop through it to get the id.